# Accessing Master Page property

Tags: .net, master-pages

I'm setting a session variable in the master page in the Page_Init event.  I then have a property on the master page that allows me to access that value.

Code on master page:

```
 public Eco.Business.User User   
{
    get { return (Eco.Business.User)Session["user"];}
    set { _user = value; }
}
```

I then do this in the page load event of a page that uses the master page (class for the master page is SiteMaster).

```
 SiteMaster m = new SiteMaster();
    Eco.Business.User _user = new Eco.Business.User();
    _user = m.User;
```

Can figure out why the property in the master page is not being set. It is always null.  But the session Session["user"] has something. I know this because I saw it in the debugger. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, I think you will want to set the object in the Session in the property definition as well:

```
public Eco.Business.User User   
{
    get { return (Eco.Business.User)Session["user"];}
    set { Session["user"] = value; }
}
```